# How to get the values of y coordinate for equidistant values of x coordinate from a plot obtained by numerically solving a differential equation?

Tags: plotting, coordinate

[image]

I need to find the value of $V[r_{*}]$  at equidistant values of $r_{*}$ (say $r_{*}$ goes from 0 to 10 in steps of 0.1) from the graph. Is it possible? I used the code

```
List @@ First@Cases[vrstar, Line[__], Infinity] // First
```

but it gives the values of $V[r_{*}]$ at $r_{*}$ which are not properly equidistant.

Need further help in this context. Thank you.

Comment: since you have the solution $V(r)$, why not just use a `Table`  to generate these values?

Comment: To iterate on @Nasser's comment: use [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) to construct an interpolation of your `list1`, and then use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to evaluate this interpolation at points of your choosing.

Comment: Yes I had already done  the Interpolation. Thank you. But still I am curious if there are some other way out.@Roman

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you require concrete assistance with extracting points and creating a table (as suggested in the comments so far) then you should upload enough Mathematica code so that respondents can experiment with it. Best of luck.